# Thread-Safe implementation of an object that deletes itself

Tags: c++, multithreading, callback, thread-safety, mutex

I have an object that is called from two different threads and after it was called by both it destroys itself by "delete this".

How do I implement this thread-safe? Thread-safe means that the object never destroys itself exactly one time (it must destroys itself after the second callback).

I created some example code:

```
class IThreadCallBack                                                                                             
{                                                                                                                 
  virtual void CallBack(int) = 0;                                                                                 
};                                                                                                                

class M: public IThreadCallBack                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                 
private:                                                                                                          
  bool t1_finished, t2_finished;                                                                                  

public:                                                                                                           

  M(): t1_finished(false), t2_finished(false)                                                                     
  {                                                                                                               
    startMyThread(this, 1);                                                                                       
    startMyThread(this, 2);                                                                                       
  }                                                                                                               

  void CallBack(int id)                                                                                           
  {                                                                                                               
    if (id == 1)                                                                                                  
    {                                                                                                             
      t1_finished = true;                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                             
    else                                                                                                          
    {                                                                                                             
      t2_finished = true;                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                             

    if (t1_finished && t2_finished)                                                                               
    {                                                                                                             
      delete this;                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                             
  }                                                                                                               
};                                                                                                                

int main(int argc, char **argv) {                                                                                 
  M* MObj = new M();                                                                                              
  while(true);                                                                                                    
}
```

Obviously I can't use a Mutex as member of the object and lock the delete, because this would also delete the Mutex. On the other hand, if I set a "toBeDeleted"-flag inside a mutex-protected area, where the finised-flag is set, I feel unsure if there are situations possible where the object isnt deleted at all.
Note that the thread-implementation makes sure that the callback method is called exactly one time per thread in any case.

Edit / Update:
What if I change Callback(..) to:

```
void CallBack(int id)

{    
  mMutex.Obtain()
  if (id == 1)
  {
    t1_finished = true;
  }
  else
  {
    t2_finished = true;
  }
  bool both_finished = (t1_finished && t2_finished);

  mMutex.Release();

  if (both_finished)
  {
    delete this;     
  }
}
```

Can this considered to be safe? (with mMutex being a member of the m class?)

I think it is, if I don't access any member after releasing the mutex?!

Comment: Auto delete ? Why this object coulnd't be destroyed by the threads which use it ?

Comment: Having objects delete themselves is A Bad Idea.

Comment: There two reasons, why the thread using it cannot delete it:
1. The two threads don't know of each other
2. The threads are belonging to an external library.

Comment: Why not use a smart pointer, which will handle reference counting for you?

Comment: Neil: When the object does not delete itself,  who should do it? The callbacks are made from an external library, so they can't. In my code there is no "Manager" that could do that. But even if there was one, this is no direct solution for the threadin issue.

Comment: Just to update it: I think the solution to my real problem is, to instrument the external libarary to use only one thread to handle my two requests. After reading API documentation I think it is possible. (The method startMyThread() in the example code was a simplification).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Boost's Smart Pointer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).  It handles this automatically; your object won't have to delete itself, and it is thread safe.

**Edit**:
From the code you've posted above, I can't really say, need more info.  But you could do it like this: each thread has a shared_ptr object and when the callback is called, you call shared_ptr::reset().  The last reset will delete M.  Each shared_ptr could be stored with [thread local storeage](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.1/gcc/Thread-Local.html) in each thread.  So in essence, each thread is responsible for its own shared_ptr.

Comment: If this option is available it is definitely better than any other I can think of.

Comment: Who is responsible for the smart pointer? The callbacks are made from external library.

Comment: @IanH I've added more details.

Comment: @Ian: each copy of the smart pointer are responsible for the deletion of the object.  Think of it as a crude kind of garbage collection where as soon as the last reference to an object gets explicitly reset or goes out of scope then the object will get deleted.

Comment: I don't have access to the thread local storage because the threads are started from an external library.

Comment: @IanH Yes you do have access.  All you need to do is declare the variable as a thread local (look at the compiler's docs to see how).  Once the thread, no matter where it was created, accesses the variable, it will be its own copy of it.  No need to alter the external library or anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using two separate flags, you could consider setting a counter to the number of threads that you're waiting on and then using interlocked decrement.

Then you can be 100% sure that when the thread counter reaches 0, you're done and should clean up.

For more info on interlocked decrement [on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683614(VS.85).aspx), [on Linux](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html#Atomic-Builtins), and [on Mac](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2006/May/msg00289.html).

Comment: OK, I stand corrected.  It's possible.  Glad it ain't me though.

Comment: Okay, i think my example was simplified too much.

In reality if have additional callback-parameters (successfull or not) and it does make a difference if the first thread is successful, while the second one does not matter (I just have to wait for either successfull nor unsuccessfull callback).
Furthermore I have to notify another component (via a asychnronous message mechanism) about the success (or failure) exactly one time.

I will update my example code soon.

Answer (score 2):

I once implemented something like this that avoided the ickiness and confusion of `delete this` entirely, by operating in the following way:

- Start a thread that is responsible for deleting these sorts of shared objects, which waits on a condition
- When the shared object is no longer being used, instead of deleting itself, have it insert itself into a thread-safe queue and signal the condition that the deleter thread is waiting on
- When the deleter thread wakes up, it deletes everything in the queue

If your program has an event loop, you can avoid the creation of a separate thread for this by creating an event type that means "delete unused shared objects" and have some persistent object respond to this event in the same way that the deleter thread would in the above example.

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine that this is possible, especially within the class itself.  The problem is two fold:

1) There's no way to notify the outside world not to call the object so the outside world has to be responsible for setting the pointer to 0 after calling "CallBack" iff the pointer was deleted.

2) Once two threads enter this function you are, and forgive my french, absolutely fucked.  Calling a function on a deleted object is UB, just imagine what deleting an object while someone is in it results in.

I've never seen "delete this" as anything but an abomination.  Doesn't mean it isn't sometimes, on VERY rare conditions, necessary.  Problem is that people do it way too much and don't think about the consequences of such a design.

I don't think "to be deleted" is going to work well.  It might work for two threads, but what about three?  You can't protect the part of code that calls delete because you're deleting the protection (as you state) and because of the UB you'll inevitably cause.  So the first goes through, sets the flag and aborts....which of the rest is going to call delete on the way out?

Comment: 1) is met because it is absolutely made sure that each thread calls back only one time. No one else knows about the object and the pointer to it.

2) Thats exactly my problem. I thought the external library was using ONE event-loop so both callbacks arrive in the same thread, but today I was told this is not the case.

Regarding "delete this": Who should delete the object? The external library doing the callback cannot be changed. And if I would use a manager-class to manage my object this would not solve the threading issue, because setting a "toBeDeleted" flag could go wrong in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The more robust implementation would be to implement reference counting. For each thread you start, increase a counter; for each callback call decrease the counter and if the counter has reached zero, delete the object. You can `lock` the counter access, or you could use the [`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) class to protect the counter access, though in that case you need to be careful with potential race between the first thread finishing and the second starting.

**Update**: And of course, I completely ignored the fact that this is C++. :-) You should use `InterlockExchange` to update the counter instead of the C# `Interlocked` class.